# Tab 2 10.1 keeps turning on

Tags: power-on, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-10.1

I bought a Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 last year and it's been working great.  Then I noticed the other day when I tried to turn off the tablet (by holding down the power butter), it just recycles and comes back on.  It will go to sleep mode but it will NOT turn off completely.  I think the latest update may have had something to do with this.  Thoughts anybody?

Answer (score 0):

i've had the same issue occur with the same symptoms.  used to work fine and then randomly started re-cycling as you mentioned.  several forums indicate this to be a pervasive issue as a result of a recent update.

i just chatted with samsung tech support and they recommended a factory reset.  it worked.  but i worry as to whether it will just eventually re-download the update the caused the issue in the first place...